# equivalent of normxcorr2 in R?

Tags: r

Do you know if it exists a function in R or R package equivalent to the `normxcorr2()` of Matlab?

I would like to compute the cross correlation of a 2D matrix, and display the cross correlation coefficients in function of the lags in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  `ccf()` from the `stats` package?  (`stats` should already be part of your R installation)

Comment: Yes I have tried and figured that it only computes the cross-correlation in one dimension. From what I understood in the help, it cannot take two lags x- and y-dimension.

Comment: Thanks though for the idea. I actually found a package called ncf that has multiple functions for cross correlation. When I play with it and plug a simple sinusoidal surface, it does not return the proper output (i.e. the function cor2()).

Comment: I also actually found the equation that is used to compute the correlation: [link](http://www.idiom.com/~zilla/Papers/nvisionInterface/nip.html#eq1:normcc).  I could easily write in terms of loop (no efficient), but harder to visualize it in terms of linear algebra.